# Advance Join Two Tables ON LIKE in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So say I have two tables, each with one column (for simplicity):

| Google Search Queries | Pop Culture Categories (Name, Event, etc) |
| --- | --- |
| Betty White Death | BTS |
| Grown Ups 2 ending | Miley Cyrus |

My goal is to join both tables to match the Google Search Query, with the Pop Culture Category. For example:

| Google Search Queries | Pop Culture Categories |
| --- | --- |
| Betty White Death | Betty White |
| Grown Ups 2 ending | Grown Ups 2 |

I attempted to do this by this Join Condition:

```
SELECT (columns)
FROM Google Search Queries
JOIN Pop Culture Categories ON Query LIKE CONCAT('%', Pop Culture, '%')
```

The problem is, it pulls in categories within the word of a query, such as BET (like the awards) or OWN (Oprah Winfrey Network). See below:

| Google Search Queries | Pop Culture Categories |
| --- | --- |
| Betty White Death | Betty White |
| Betty White Death | BET |
| Grown Ups 2 ending | Grown Ups 2 |
| Grown Ups 2 ending | OWN |

Is there a way I could simply join the query to the full category, without having it pull out categories that are within a word of the search query?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need (at a minimum) an `ON` condition that uses a regular expression. To do this right, you'd probably want to pre-process the search terms to extract relevant terms, correct common misspellings, etc. To simply match and avoid matching partial words, you can do this (the one at the bottom is what it needs - the others show why it's necessary to do it that way):

```
select REGEXP_INSTR( 'Betty White' , 'BET'  , 1 , 1, 0 , 'im') > 0; -- Returns TRUE. Matches the substring - similar to ilike %BET%

select REGEXP_INSTR( 'Betty White' , '\\bBET\\b'  , 1 , 1, 0 , 'im') > 0; -- Returns FALSE. Matches whole words only. 

select REGEXP_INSTR( 'Grown Ups 2 ending' , '\\bGrown Ups 2\\b'  , 1 , 1, 0 , 'im') > 0; -- Works okay if there are no extra spaces

select REGEXP_INSTR( 'Grown  Ups 2 ending' , '\\bGrown\\s*Ups\\s*2\\b'  , 1 , 1, 0 , 'im') > 0; -- Deals with extra spaces. 

set col1 = 'Grown  Ups 2 ending';
set col2 = 'Grown Ups 2';

select REGEXP_INSTR( $col1 , $col2  , 1 , 1, 0 , 'im') > 0; -- Won't work... Need to dynamically construct the pattern.

select REGEXP_INSTR( $col1 , '\\b' || replace($col2, ' ', '\\s*') || '\\b' , 1 , 1, 0 , 'im') > 0; -- This works as long as there's only one space on the Pop Culture side
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the category name is always a subset of the Google Search Queries and the GSQ never starts with somehting different that is not the category, then you can just get rid of the initial % in the LIKE.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are GSQ's where like "How Old is Elon Musk" and I'd want that to match to "Elon Musk"

Comment: Maybe add an OR for the case that the category is at the end. It would at least work with "How Old is Elon Musk".